# Expanding an object to set attributes in Jade

Tags: templates, attributes, pug

I would like to be able to pass in an object with key/value pairs that represent attributes for an element.  Is this possible with Jade?

Any solution that allows me to pass an attributes collection into my template would be sufficient, but the ability to mix explicitly declared attributes with attributes extracted from an object (as below) would be ideal.

**The following syntax does not work, it is just an example of what I'd like to do.**

For example, if I passed this:

```
{ 
    name:'username',
    value:'bob',
    attributes: {
        maxlength: 16
    }
}
```

To this template:

```
input(name=name, value=value, attributes)
```

The desired output would be:

```
<input name="username" value="bob" maxlength="16" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are a part of [this issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/664#issuecomment-32261710) on GitHub, you probably already know the answer. But, for anyone else, here is the answer:

Jade:

```
input.foo(name=name value=value)&attributes(attrs)
```

Pass this data to your render function:

```
{
    name: 'username',
    value: 'bob',
    attrs: {
        maxlength: 16
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<input name="username" value="bob" class="foo" maxlength="16"/>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. This has been here for a while and I had honestly forgotten it was here. As noted in the github issue: **&attributes does not escape output so use with caution**

Comment: Good to know. I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a object name or use the keyword 'global' like this:

```
partial('myview', { { 
    name:'username',
    value:'bob',
    attributes: {
        maxlength: 16
    }
}, as: global });
```

otherwise you need to give your object a name and access them through that scope.

[Check out the docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-partials)

Comment: This doesn't, in any way, address the substance of the question. I'm trying to figure out how to take an object that contains a list of attributes and apply those attributes to a tag in my template.  E.g. `input(attributes)` where attributes is an object with attribute names as keys and attribute values as values. I don't need to rename `locals`.

Comment: apologies Prestaul, I misunderstood the question. Please post your answer if and when you find one.