# Syntax Using Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, pug

I am a seasoned Developer, however, I am on a project with a team that uses Jade and I am trying to get some syntax figured out.

How do I add attributes to a Input box to do a 
maxlength: 20?

Right now the tag looks like this

input#address-name(type='text', name='address[name]', value=cart.address.name)
I want to add a Maxlength option to this input box.

I checked on jades website and do not see an example like this.
I am sure it is somewhat trivial, the problem is that this project is live so I do not really have time for trial and error and would like to just get the syntax right the first time around.

Thanks again !

Comment: try locally yourself first and ask question if have any problem in code

Comment: I do not have the environment set up locally, It is a platform that is using multiple servers.
So i cannot test locally, else i would have.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

```
input#address-name(type='text', name='address[name]', value=cart.address.name, maxlength="20")
```

If you're not OK with Jade, this site will help you to translate regular HTML to Jade (which were renamed to "Pug"):

http://html2jade.org/

Comment: Thank you for an answer isntead of just talking crap about me testing locally, Obviouslly i would of went that route if it was possible.
I am glad you said something too becausse what i found onlin ewas something like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864196/expanding-an-object-to-set-attributes-in-jade

input.foo(name=name value=value)&attributes(maxlength: 20)